# How to make date cell selection with square instead of circle FSCalendar Swift 3

Tags: swift, fscalendar

I'm using [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar) and the cell selection set to circle by default

like this:

[image]

how to make cell selection to square?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
calendar.appearance.borderRadius = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do Also By its own enum value in viewDidLoad()

calendar.appearance.borderRadius = .zero

Paste the Code in ViewDidLoad it will Run Happily :)

Comment: You might have written this as a comment on the other answer, since this is technically a duplicate answer

Comment: No @zoran404 I Have also Suggested that "by its own enum value" as you can see.